# Case Management

Tags: email, workflow, email2case

Email to Case is Setup as Queue email address e.g. ABC@HOME.com

New Case Notification is created to and forth in Case Email Section, when Case Owner is Queue (ABC@HOME.com).

Queue Case Owner ABC@HOME.com sends End User email via Case, but redundancy occurs when End User replies to Case Owner ABC@HOME.com. But if it's assigned to Case Individual Owner, no replication of New Case Notification appears.

Have disabled notify to case owner but yet not sure what's triggering, NOREPLY@SALESFORCE new case notification to Case Email. Not sure if any workflow will help to resolve the issue.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please check if the sender and receiver are same.